# What is the best way to tell what type of "display" css bootstrap uses for any given element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If I'm using JS to modify the "display" property of a bootstrap "row" or "col-md-3" for example--what is the best way to know what the default value is that bootstrap css uses?

For example--the bootstrap source code must use "block" or "inline-block" for the "row" class. If my JS changes it to "display: none" and I want to change it back later, what is the best way to know what to change it back to?

Comment: Just return it to `element.style.display = ""`, i.e. empty string and it will adopt its default or inherited display value.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. An empty string seems to do nothing, while block works on a few of them. So my original question remains

Comment: In that case, the display is being set by script too, so you'll need to remember what it was initially and reset it to that, or use gavgrif's solution with a class.

Comment: you may wanna look at bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js file that comes with every download of bootstrap to see how classes are displayed in bootstrap

Comment: Thinking about this some more, I'm wondering if your approach is a little off.  Maybe you should just add a class to the element as opposed to trying to muck with the element.style.  That's usually how I do it.  Then you can just toggle your class and get back to the original bootstrap value.  But, maybe you're under some constraints?

Answer (score 0):

Use js to add a class to the element and this class has CSS of display:none. Then when you want to revert to the visible portion - remove the added class. That way you are not altering the css of the bootstrap element directly.

```
//css
.hiddenElement{
display:none !important;
}

//js
$('#elementTo_Alter').addClass('hiddenElement') //adds the class and hides the element

//to return to regular styling
$('#elementTo_Alter').removeClass('hiddenElement') //removes the class and displays the element
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is save a copy of the original computed styles for the element. In this case, you can use window.getComputedStyle(element) to get the list of computed styles.

But you have to go a bit further to make it easier to replace the original styles after they have been changed.

This should work:

```
//grab one or more elements
var row = document.getElementsByClassName("row")[0];

//store the style
var css = window.getComputedStyle(row);
var cssObject = {};

//make it into an object to handle specifics
for (var i = 0; i < css.length; i++) {
        cssObject[css[i]] = css.getPropertyValue(""+css[i]);
}

//change color
row.style.color = "red";

//eventually replace original color
setTimeout(function(){
  row.style.color = cssObject.color;
  console.log(cssObject.color);
}, 2000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mxt4y2eh/

Comment: But this approach will convert inherited and computed styles to hard coded values, which will likely have issues. E.g. background colour might be inherited, but this will hard code it.

Comment: @RobG, There doesn't seem to be a better way to get styles after they are applied.  If you used element.style() you would only get those inlined, (not from the head). In the case of bootstrap, it looks like it applies the styles dynamically after initial paint?  So maybe this is the best approach for OP?